# Android install button on tablets doesn't work

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet

When I try to install my app on tablets I get to the screen where it says "Do you want to install this app?" and I can only press the cancel button, not the install button (but it looks normal). I activated installation from unknown sources setting and the android version is late enough. My Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>

<supports-screens

    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"

    />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I thought the supports-screens tag would solve the problem but obviously it does not.
If code or other files are necessary please tell me.
I can install the app on a tablet in the android studio emulator. There is no error message and it's the first time I encounter this.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you tried installing from command line or android studio?

Comment: i mailed me the apk and opened it

Comment: try turning app verification off. refer [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2812853?hl=en) for steps.

Comment: thanks for your help but Sander solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with your app, I had this problem with any apk I tried to install. Do you have any apps installed that affect your screen, like [Bluelight Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.hardyinfinity.bluelightfilter.free&hl=en)? Removing those should solve the problem.

Comment: yes i have this app installed. i will immediately try it!